# Electrum Addresses for Customer Rewards Program

Tags: electrum, address-reuse

We are a tour company, I want to create a simple BTC rewards program for our travellers. Buy a tour from us and receive $20 BTC. Customer unlikely to have a wallet to begin with thus we need to hold it under their name. The customer may at some stage want to take custody, the customer may want to spend it with us on their next tour, they may want to stack the rewards they receive i.e save for a bigger purchase.
Will Electrum work for this?
Can I assign an address in Electrum to a specific customer using the Label Column. Each time they purchase we send there BTC reward to that customers Labeled address.

We have about 600 purchasing customers, thus would need 600 labelled addresses.

Could Electrum be suitable or can you suggest a wallet which maybe able to do somthing like this?

Answer (score 0):

> can you suggest a wallet which maybe able to do somthing like this?

None or any.

I would just use a spreadsheet to keep a list of names and amounts (BTC equivalent of $20 at date of qualification)

If I was worried about exchange rate fluctuations I would buy enough BTC at the end of a week or month to cover the customer rewards that qualifies in that period. I would use any single-user wallet and not use the wallet to correlate amounts to customers.

When a customer wanted to "withdraw" I would just use that wallet to send the address the customer gave me a BTC amount noted in the spreadsheet.

For 600 x $20 ($12,000) I wouldn't expect to find an existing comprehensive solution that meets all my needs and which can be purchased/rented and integrated into my existing systems for much less than that amount.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, yes using a excel sheet was my default option :-) Do you know if you can link a live price of BTC to an excell sheet and formula, in order to provide a portfolio total to the customer? with out calculating outside of the spreadsheet?

Comment: I don't know of a way to link live exchange rates in MS-Excel - sorry :-(